# In CSS why is text-align:-webkit-center working for me when text-align:center; is not?

Tags: html, css, webkit

I'm making a sharepoint 2010 page and the code below is centering the table successfully in the middle of the page, but when I remove the -webkit- from the code, it no longer centers. Why doesn't "text-align: center;" work? Another weird thing is that the -webkit- only makes the centering work in Chrome. Centering this table seems impossible in all other browsers.

```
<style>
.s4-wpcell-plain{
text-align: -webkit-center;
}
</style>



<table style="width:100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td id="MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2" valign="top" class="s4-wpcell-plain">

<!-- content -->

</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It does work with `center`...I just created a fiddle here to demonstrate: https://jsfiddle.net/Lv0Lnc1y/

Comment: @WayneAllen for some reason in Sharepoint 2010 that doesn't work. Is there possibly something in a sharepoint web part that is overriding my attempts to center?

Comment: I am not familiar with Sharepoint, but I suspect that if you examine the element using developer tools, you will find some other class or style is overriding the CSS style you are setting.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that webparts in sharepoint can't be centered. I used margin-left and margin-right: auto.

Comment: You *can* center them. *That's* how you center them - with auto horizontal margins.

Answer (score -1):

The css property "text-align : center" is working for all the browser. whereas the  -webkit- is CSS prefix for Safari browser and can also be used with Chrome. So, it will not work with other browsers.